# I'm trying to fetch a Twitter Hashtag for a TableView, however I receive a SIGABRT with my current code

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, hashtag

I am able to have it fill my tableview with a user timeline, but not a specific hashtag. I have already checked the Twitter API version 1.1, but that doesn't work as well. I'm wondering if anyone has any tips or solutions? The portion of the code I'm using is as follows:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return tweets.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath            *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TweetCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier   forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSDictionary *tweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *name = [tweet objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *text = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];
cell.textLabel.text = name;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = text;

NSLog(@"Count Number in tweets array: %d",tweets.count);

    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}

return cell;
}


-(void)fetchTweets
{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0),^
{

    NSData* data2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:      @"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q==%23twitter"]];

    NSError * error;

    tweets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data2 options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[self.tableView reloadData];
    });
});
}
```

As I said before, I have already checked the Twitter API 1.1, which gives this URL as a sample: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23freebandnames&since_id=24012619984051000&max_id=250126199840518145&result_type=mixed&count=4
Thank you for your help and your time, I really appreciate it! :)